# How to solve this question using binomial expansion and identities?

Tags: polynomials, binomial-theorem

If $m,n$ are positive integers and
 $$(1+ x + x^2 + x^3... + x^n)^m = a + a'x + a''x^2 + a'''x^3...$$
Prove that the value of $$a' + 3a'' + 6a''' + 10a'''' ...= \frac{mn(2m+1)^n(3mn+n-2)}{6}$$
I tried to open the the given polynomial as a GP and expressing coefficient of any general term, and then summing the term required for expression but was unable to reach answer.

Any alternate way or any improvisation?

Answer (score 1):

(Let us call $a^{i}{'}=a_i$)

**Hint :**
$$\text{Your sum is}~:~\sum \Big(\frac{n^2-n}{2}\Big)a_n=\sum \frac{n^2}{2}a_n-\sum \frac{n}{2}a_n$$

For $\sum n^2a_n$ : Differentiate both the sides, then multiply by $x$, differentiate again , then put $x=1$

For $\sum na_n$ : Differentiate and put $x=1$

Can you procced now?

Comment: The general term is (n²-n)/2 a, rather but anyways thanks i just forgot the term by term differentiation silly me and went on differentiating ((1-x^2m+1)/(1-x))^n creating complications... :-(

Comment: @AshPd Thanks , I have corrected.

Comment: Its ( n² - n )/2..